# Using Zend Lucene to search PDF files

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

Is there a way to use Zend_Search_Lucene to search/index PDF documents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.kapustabrothers.com/2008/01/20/indexing-pdf-documents-with-zend_search_lucene/

Comment: I don't know if it's only today but it gives me a broken link